# How many values does the fixpoint of Endo have?

Tags: haskell, types, topology

Consider the following datatype:

```
newtype EndoFix = EndoFix {appEndoFix :: EndoFix -> EndoFix}
```

This is essentially the fixpoint of `Endo` from `Data.Monoid`. I wondered what values this type has. Some examples:

```
example0 = EndoFix id
example1 = EndoFix (const example0)
example2 = EndoFix (const example1)
```

This quickly leads us to a limit point:

```
import Data.Function
exampleOmega = fix (EndoFix . const)
```

However, I couldn't find any semidecision procedure that distinguishes these values. My intuition tells there is none, meaning that these values actually are all equal. So what's the actual topological space expressed by `EndoFix`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing you can observe from this type is non-termination.

In terms of "fast and loose" reasoning, where you ignore non-termination, this type is a unit type (only one inhabitant/all inhabitants are undistinguishable). One formal argument here is that you can prove in Martin-Lof Type Theory that there cannot be a type `T` with an isomorphism `(T -> T) <-> T` and two distinct elements (`x, y : T`, such that `x != y`). (By a diagonal argument, or more abstractly, [Lawvere's fixed point theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere%27s+fixed+point+theorem). You might also have to assume decidable equality, which might be quite strong depending on your point of view, but still means that you will need to rely on a fancy model to exhibit a counterexample)

This means that if there is anything nontrivial about `Fix Endo`, it must be in the blind spot of "pretending Haskell is total / like type theory", i.e., it must involve non-termination.

We can distinguish `example0`, `example1`, and `example2` by passing them some undefined arguments and forcing them.

```
-- force1 example0 = _|_
-- force1 example1 = () 
force1 :: EndoFix -> ()
force1 f = (f `appEndoFix` undefined) `seq` ()

-- force2 example1 = _|_
-- force2 example2 = ()
force2 :: EndoFix -> ()
force2 f = ((f `appEndoFix` undefined) `appEndoFix` undefined) `seq` ()
```

Using that idea, you can define infinitely many distinguishable functions: there are at least those that take n arguments and return the i-th argument.

An interpretation of `EndoFix` would basically be a denotational semantics for the untyped lambda calculus, with `seq` as an extra feature.

```
-- HOAS embedding of untyped lambda calculus in EndoFix
app :: EndoFix -> EndoFix -> EndoFix
lam :: (EndoFix -> EndoFix) -> EndoFix
```

A well-known example is given by Dana Scott in [Continuous Lattices](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3229/PRG07.pdf) (which culminates in Theorem 4.4). The general idea is to consider `F a = a -> a` as an operation on lattices/CPOs, and construct `EndoFix` as the limit of its iterated applications `F^n ∅`. So one way to approach this space is to enumerate the inhabitants of `F^n ∅` for small values of `n`.

Another relevant resource is the chapter on [Denotational Semantics of Untyped Lambda Calculus](https://plfa.github.io/20.07/Denotational/) in Programming Language Foundations in Agda, which gives a more concrete definition.